# Getting very very large number suddenly

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

when I'm training my keras deep learning mode, suddenly I'm getting very very large number in loss.
My data is imbalance binay class in the ratio of 1:7, and I'm using AUC score.

Please see the below snap
[image]

and because if imbalanced dataset I'm also getting getting following error how
to handle this situation.
[image]

Comment: what do you want us to do

Comment: I would like to know why that sudden increase in loss?

Comment: it shows that keeping the value of epoch as 2 will be best for you. The loss can behave in any way when you are using epochs, Yes generally with datasets it increase or decrease gradually but in your case your data is of imbalance binaries

Answer (score 0):

Make your batches such that there are both the classes in the batch that is created. So, rather than directly loading and putting the data in the network. Segregate examples of both classes, 1 of lower class and 7 of higher class. Or make the dataset balanced by reducing the number of examples of higher class.